# Comparing a parsed date with momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-formatting

I would test if string date value in local french format is after a specific date.

```
const value = moment("vendredi 5 avril 2019").isAfter('2019-04-03');
console.log(value);
```

Actually I get result `false` but it should be true.

Is there a moment or JS method to convert local string date to a date format ?

The inverse of `toLocalString()`

**EDIT:**

I have updated my code

```
const _text= "vendredi, 5 avril 2019";
var format = 'LLLL, Do MMMM YYYY, h:mm:ss a';
const newDate= moment(_text, format, 'fr')
                  .locale('en')
                  .format('MMMM Do YYYY');
console.log(newDate);
const value = moment(newDate).isAfter('2019-04-03');
console.log(value);
```

It converts my french date to english

```
April 5th 2019
```

but I get always `false` when comparing `April 5th 2019` to `2019-04-03`

Comment: maybe you can use direct moment(_text, format, 'fr') to compare with predefined datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to format the date for the comparison `newDate` as `YYYY-MM-DD`. This is a working example based on your code:

```
const moment = require('moment');

const _text= "vendredi, 5 avril 2019";
var format = 'LLLL, Do MMMM YYYY, h:mm:ss a';
const newDate= moment(_text, format, 'fr')
                  .locale('en')
                  .format('YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log(newDate);
const value = moment(newDate).isAfter('2019-04-03');
console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you convert the parsed date to another string and compare it to your date?

If you just parse the french date and compare the result to `2019-04-03`, you get the expected result :

```js
const _text= "vendredi, 5 avril 2019";
var format = 'LLLL, Do MMMM YYYY, h:mm:ss a';
const newDate= moment(_text, format, 'fr');
const isAfter = newDate.isAfter('2019-04-03');
console.log(isAfter);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/fr.js"></script>
```